# How to auto zoom the grafana dashboard to fit to the data and bins on x axis

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I have a grafana dashboard where I am pushing the time series for display purpose. The problem is that I need to zoom in and out depending on the data range. Is there any method to do this automatically

Comment: Did you find a way how to do this?

Comment: The graph is not of much use if we can't do this. If I click away I can click zoom to data and it will do it. But surely it should be automatic? Did you find a way yet Saurabh ?